# Bootstrap 5 autofit column width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Having the following code ([pen here](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/gOvRypK)), I tried to autofit the second column width to its content with auto margins that does not seem to work.

```css
.col {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.autofit {
  margin: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row m-5">
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col autofit">2*</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
  <div class="col">4</div>
</div>
```

Is there another way to autofit the column width?

I also tried `width: fit-content(100px);`, but it didn't work either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Bootstrap-class `.col-auto` for this. Simple and effective!

```css
.col, .col-auto {
  border: 1px solid red;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row m-5">
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col-auto">2*</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
  <div class="col">4</div>
</div>
```